# Finding the initial conditions for system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

How to find out the the initial conditions for the below system of first order autonomous differential equation i.e $x_1(0)=? , x_2(0)=?, x_3(0)=? \\
 \frac{dx_1}{dn} = -4-3x_1+2x_3-x_1x_3+x_1^2 \\
\frac{dx_2}{dn} = 8-4x_3+x_2x_1-2x_2x_3+4x_2 \\
 \frac{dx_2}{dn} = -8 + 8x_3-2x_3^2$

Comment: There is information missing in the task, and also what your question about the task is. Is this about stationary/fixed/equilibrium points? Then you have to solve 3 quadratic equations, by the occurring variables the elimination order would be $x_3,x_1,x_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my problem $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are different functions of $n$ and I know how to solve the system for the given initial conditions and also calculated the stationary/fixed/equilibrium points. If you can give some reference to figure out how initial conditions to be chosen it will be helpful for me.

Comment: It is still not clear what the task is, the initial conditions are free variables, as you said, you can compute a solution for each value of them. So it has to be some condition of the solution that in reverse determine the initial values that you are looking for. What condition is that? For stationary points, the derivative is zero, so that you get algebraic equations.

Comment: I'm really for the above ambiguous conversation. I got it what are you trying to infer. Thanks a lot for answering the question.